# Markov inequality and Boundness in probability

Tags: self-study, asymptotics, probability-inequalities, bounds

Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{a_n\}$ be sequences of random variables and real numbers, respectively.

Say that $X_n=O_P(a_n)$ iff $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N,M>0$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $P(\lvert X_n/a_n \rvert>M)\leq\epsilon$.

In my case, I have $E\lvert X_n \rvert\leq C a_n$, where $C$ is some positive constant. Markov's inequality yields given any $\epsilon>0$,
$$P(\lvert X_n/a_n \rvert>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E\lvert X_n \rvert}{a_n\epsilon}\leq \frac{C}{\epsilon}.$$

My question (probably naive) is that if it is enough to conclude that $X_n=O_p(a_n)$. I'm thinking that if I identify $\epsilon':=1/\epsilon$ and note that the range of $\epsilon'$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$, then it implies the result.

Can you clarify me this point?

Comment: I would say your reasoning is entirely correct. You might have confused yourself a bit with notation - you used $\epsilon$ twice to mean rather different things.

Comment: @sjm.majewski In what part I used your refered  epsilon incorrectly?

Comment: The proof is correct. I was just wondering why you might have thought that it was not, and hypothetized that maybe using the same symbol $\epsilon$ in the definition of $O_P$ and in Markov inequality, where they play different roles, might have confused you. But the reasoning is entirely correct, and that is what matters.